# BASH: How to replace a value in a matrix?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a matrix of mxn. I want to replace the `pattern1` with a word and that pattern is at row 3, column 4.

**How can I do that?**

So far... I know how to acces to the value at row 3 and column 4:

```
awk 'NR==3' $1 | awk -vvar="4" '{print $var}'
```

But ... how can I replace that pattern located at that cell?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: `awk 'NR==3 {$4="replacement"}1' file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==3{ sub("pattern", "replacement", $4) } 1' "$1"
```

- `sub`: one of the substitution functions. See [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) for more information
- `1`: idiomatic way of saying `{ print $0 }`